# About strings and substrings

Tags: scheme, racket

How would you design a function that consumes a string and a number i which inserts "_" at the ith position of the string?

```
(define (string-insert n i)
  (substring n i))
```

I just need to add the `"_"` at the ith position which is driving me crazy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `string-append` and `substring`, the trick is to get the indexes right:

```
(define (string-insert n i)
  (string-append
   (substring n <???> <???>)
   "_"
   (substring n <???>)))
```

I'll let you figure out the details, you'll see that it works as expected:

```
(string-insert "HelloWorld" 5)
=> "Hello_World"
```